# How do I store a date value from DatePicker into a formatted String value?

Tags: android, datepicker

During the signup process, I'm trying to implement a code that stores a date value into a string value in the following format: "dd-mm-yyyy".

So, on the onCreate() method part, I declared a DatePicker variable as follows:

```
DatePicker dob = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dob);
```

And on the onClick() method part, I wrote a code to convert this DatePicker value into the String.

```
String entered_dob = dob.toString();
```

But later when I opened the database I found out that this only returns a value which looks nonsense. How should I implement in order to get what I wanted?

Comment: ricoangeloni did any of the answers help you solve the problem. Remeber to mark the correct answer or even answer your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store your date as a String (which is not a good practice)

```
DatePicker datePicker ;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter ;
Date d ;
String entered_dob ;

datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dob);

int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
int year = datePicker.getYear()

d = new Date(year, month, day);
dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
entered_dob = dateFormatter.format(d);
```

If you want to get the timestamp you can do it like this

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
long enterded_dob_ts = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Thanks! But why is your first suggestion not a good practice?

Comment: @ricoangeloni timestamps can be used to compare two dates directly (since they are a long number) on the other hand storing dates in a specific format make it hard to understand and operate. Is "01-02-2013" January 2nd or February 1st ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the timestamp.

Use the [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) to create this value. This one you can easily store as long (or string if you really want this)

Checkout [this Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But can you show me an example? I'm a relatively newbie to programming..